# how to pull data from sql server api using Codeigniter or PHP

Tags: php, jquery, api, codeigniter

My sql server created api is given below

```
http://0.0.0.0/XHost/api/General/[{Employee_ID}]

Example: http://0.0.0.0/XHost/api/General/0123456789
```

I have a api with real ip like above.

I am using Codeigiter, I would like to pull/get data from sql server via api.

Basically i will use jquery autocomplete to pull data.

How can i solve it? please any suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `rest server class` for this,

Download it from [Codeigniter-restserver](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver) Read [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/) for how to use it

And call your `api` from `jquery` like,

```
$( "#autiId" ).autocomplete({
   source: "http://0.0.0.0/XHost/api/General/0123456789",
   minLength: 2,
   select: function( event, ui ) {
      alert("Selected: " + ui.item.value + " id " + ui.item.id : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
   }
});
```

If your `emp id` is `dynamic` then `append` by getting this like,

```
var id=0123456789;
```

and `source` like,

```
source:"http://0.0.0.0/XHost/api/General/"+id
```

Comment: Basically I am using mysql(database), i need emp information other database(MS sql server). Provide me api(database ms sqlserver). I have to pull data from that api using autocomplete.

Comment: You have to change the `db connection` from `mysql` to `mssql` server for this for `api calls`